# Could you help me with this error "The method in undefined for the type"?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, methods, program-entry-point

I was trying to populate an Arraylist using asList() but I I cant understand the error Eclipse is giving me, I read other solutions but I dont know to use them for my case

```
package arraylistvirtuale;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class BankAccountArraylisttester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        BankAccount cc = new BankAccount(1115);

        ArrayList<BankAccount> accounts 
        = new ArrayList<BankAccount>(Arrays.asList(cc(1115)));
        
        accounts.add(1, new BankAccount(1008));
        accounts.remove(0);
        System.out.println("size=" + accounts.size());
        BankAccount first = accounts.get(0);
        System.out.println("first account number=" + first.getAccountNumber());
        BankAccount last = accounts.get(accounts.size()-1);
        System.out.println("last account number=" + last.getAccountNumber());
        BankAccount bankaccount= new BankAccount(2385);
        bankaccount.deposit(100.1); 
        System.out.println("balance =" + bankaccount.getBalance());
    }

}

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method cc(int) is undefined for the type BankAccountArraylisttester

    at arraylistvirtuale/arraylistvirtuale.BankAccountArraylisttester.main(BankAccountArraylisttester.java:11)
```

Comment: What do you think `cc(1115)` should mean when `cc` is a `BankAccount`? That syntax is used for calling functions and you're trying to use it on a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have already assigned a value to a variable, then use this variable. The variable already contains what you have written to it.

```
    BankAccount cc = new BankAccount(1115);
    BankAccount dd = new BankAccount(1234);
    BankAccount ee = new BankAccount(3333);
    ArrayList<BankAccount> accounts
            = new ArrayList<BankAccount>(Arrays.asList(cc, dd, ee));
```

Or:

```
   ArrayList<BankAccount> accounts
        = new ArrayList<BankAccount>(Arrays.asList(
   new BankAccount(1234);
   new BankAccount(2222);
   new BankAccount(3333);
   ));
```

asList() method fills in either list you have created or another list that has already been created.

For example:

```
 ArrayList<BankAccount> accounts
 = new ArrayList<BankAccount> 
 (Arrays.asList(name_of_another_list));
```

Comment: Ooh I think I got it now thanks, I'll try it now

Comment: Don't forget to click a "best answer" option on the answer if that helped you:)

Comment: Where can I find the option?

Comment: @DindyBa This is under the voting arrows on the left of the answer

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what you intend with `Arrays.asList(cc(1115))` -- in Java source, the syntax `x(y)` is an invocation of `x`, passing `y` as a parameter. So the error message is telling you exactly what is wrong -- there is no method named `cc` with an int as a parameter in the `BankAccountArraylisttester` class.

The `Arrays.asList()` method takes an array as a parameter; you have passed it what looks like an individual object, if we ignore the `(1115)`. So even if you remove the `(1115)`, you will have an error indicating that there is no `asList()` method taking a `BankAccountArraylisttester` as a parameter.

Perhaps you wanted to put `cc` into an `ArrayList<BankAccount>`; if so, you can create the ArrayList, then add `cc` to it:

```
ArrayList<BankAccount> accounts = new ArrayList<>();
accounts.add(cc);
```

I've speculated enough without trying to figure out what `first` and `last` are supposed to be.

Comment: I'll try to explain myself, so I was trying to use asList to populate an ArrayList of bank accounts, I have a constructor in another class for creating a bank acoount, "cc" is a name for a bankaccount. What you see below is what I used before to populate the arraylist, I was trying to emulate this but by using asList                                                                                        
ArrayList<BankAccount> accounts = new ArrayList<BankAccount>();         
accounts.add(new BankAccount(1001));
accounts.add(new BankAccount(1015));
accounts.add(new BankAccount(1015));